# Replace only leading and trailing whitespace with underscore using regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex, whitespace

I want to replace only leading and trailing white space of a string by number of underscore.

**Input String**

```
" New Folder  "
```

(Notes: There is one white space at front and two white spaces at the end of this string)

**Output**

My desire output string `"_New Folder__"`
(The output string has one underscore at the front and two underscore at the end.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is using a callback:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"^\s+|\s+$", match => match.Value.Replace(' ', '_'));
```

Or using lookaround (a bit trickier):

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<=^\s*)\s|\s(?=\s*$)", "_");
```

Comment: Looking again, `new String('_', match.Length)` might be more appropriate here. Oh well.

Comment: Definitely.  Not only is it more obvious what is being done, but it also has the benefit of handling other whitespace characters besides space.

Answer (score 1):

You may also choose a non-regex solution, but I'm not sure it's pretty:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
int length = sb.Length;
for (int postion = 0; (postion < length) && (sb[postion] == ' '); postion++)
    sb[postion] = '_';
for (int postion = length - 1; (postion > 0) && (sb[postion] == ' '); postion--)
    sb[postion] = '_';
s = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I think I've answered too many regular expression questions, I'm sure there's a better way to do this `:P`