# Replace each leading and trailing whitespace with underscore using regex in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, whitespace

```
$string = "   Some string  ";
//the output should look like this
$output = "___Some string__";
```

So each leading and trailing whitespace replaced by underscore.

I found the regex for this in C here: [Replace only leading and trailing whitespace with underscore using regex in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545468/replace-only-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-with-underscore-using-regex-in-c-sh)
but i couldn't make it work in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a replace like:

```
$output = preg_replace('/\G\s|\s(?=\s*$)/', '_', $string);
```

`\G` matches at the beginning of the string or at the end of the previous match, `(?=\s*$)` matches if the following is only whitespace at the end of the string.
So this expression matches each of the spaces and replaces them with a `_`.

Comment: @RazvanO. this isn't completely trivial to do with regex, so the regex is a bit tricky. :-)

Comment: Nice one!  Even if those other solutions did work, this is the one I would use, in .NET as well as PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex with look ahead as Qtax suggested.
An alternate solution using preg_replace_callback is :
http://codepad.org/M5BpyU6k

```
<?php
$string = " Some string       ";
$output = preg_replace_callback("/^\s+|\s+$/","uScores",$string); /* Match leading
                                                                     or trailing whitespace */
echo $output;

function uScores($matches)
{
  return str_repeat("_",strlen($matches[0]));  /* replace matches with underscore string of same length */
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

```
<?php 
$testString ="    Some test   ";

echo $testString.'<br/>';
for($i=0; $i < strlen($testString); ++$i){
  if($testString[$i]!=" ")
    break;
  else
    $testString[$i]="_";
}
$j=strlen($testString)-1;
for(; $j >=0; $j--){
  if($testString[$j]!=" ")
    break;
  else
    $testString[$j]="_";
}

echo $testString;

?>
```